# Iterate through files on a certain level

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I'm trying to iterate through all the files on a certain level in the folder hierachy, more specifically, in all the sub-sub folders. Before I do actual operations on the files, I also want to count all the files to be able to show a progress bar. This means the iterating method must be called 2 times. This is the relevant code, I'm using now:

```
    Iterate(bool count)
    {
       foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(root))
          foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
             foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
             {
                if (count) progressBar.Maximum++;          
                else 
                {
                   //do operations
                }
             }
    }
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this. Surely there must be a better way than adding a `foreach` for every folder level..?

Comment: The innermost `foreach` loop can be replaced by a call to the `Length()` property of the array returned by `GetFiles`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be easier to me to use LINQ here.

```
var files = 
    (from dir in Directory.GetDirectories(root)
     from subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
     from f in Directory.GetFiles(subdir)
     select f).ToList();

var fileCount = files.Length;
foreach (var f in files) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's pretty good. At least it eliminates the usage of if/else.

Answer (score 0):

Before your GetFiles foreach, try this:

```
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(subdir);
int intFileCount = fileEntries.length;
```

Or it can replace it, if the loop only serves to count the files.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) shows how to recursively iterate a directory tree

Answer (score 0):

you could download the fluent thing I wrote for System.IO (see here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/11/staticvoid-io-extentions-nuget.html) and then use this LINQ statement

```
        var files = from d in di.Directories()
                    from dir in d.Directories()
                    from f in dir.Files()
                    select f;
```

Answer (score 0):

write this instead your code

```
string [] files = Directory.GetFile("yourDirectory","*.*",SearchOptions.AllDirectories);
```

this will return all files in sub-directories instead of using recursion

Comment: I don't think this will work because I only want to iterate through the files on a certain level. This will return all files in the specified folder.